# Flutter Riverpod StateNotifier to not add to end of List

Tags: flutter, state-management, riverpod

im new to Riverpod and Flutter
the problem i'm having is that when i use StateNotifier, the state is immutable so i have to create new state and add new value to the end of List

```
void add(Cart cart) {
    state = [...state, cart];
}

void inQuan(int i) {
    final tempCart = state[i];
    tempCart.quantity++;
    remove(state[i]);
    add(tempCart);
}
```

and this makes my list pushes the item i'm editing to the end
is there any way to optimize my code?

Answer (score 0):

This creates only one new array.

```
  void inQuan(int i) {
    state = [
      for (int index = 0; i < state.length; index++)
        if (i == index)
          state[i].copyWith(quantity: state[i].quantity++)
        else
          state[i]
    ];
  }
```